# Error Installation on gr-gsm

Tags: software-installation, ppa

When I issued

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ptrkrysik/gr-gsm
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gr-gsm
```

I got this error

> `Error: need a single repository as argument`

Ubuntu 16.04 LT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ptrkrysik/gr-gsm sudo apt update && sudo apt install gr-gsm

is not a valid command chain. This is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ptrkrysik/gr-gsm && sudo apt update && sudo apt install gr-gsm
```

Mind the extra `&&` before the 2nd `sudo`.